# How to specify column width in tree view

Tags: odoo

I'm using OpenERP 6.0.4 GTK client and the product tree view comes up with the UoM column too wide (wider than the product name). 
Where is the place to control the column width in a tree view ?

Answer (score 3):

Techically this whole is game of CSS but if you really courious and wanna check, How stuff going on then on OpenERP Web Project under `addons/web/static/src/css/base.css` check for the class `oe_list_content` you see width are 100% at rlative postion but each field type has their own attrib too. If you check stuff with Firebug you will each cell has mutiple CSS but `oe_list_content`  in common, so all re kept in same tr, td at rleative position.

Thank You.

Comment: Please note that this does not apply to 6.0 web client. But still interesting.

Comment: Certailny I am tlak ing about trunk web client. Noehter 6.1 too.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I didn't note at beginning that I am asking for GTK client.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can't. The closest thing would be to use the `colspan="x"` field attribute, but unfortunately that doesn't work in tree views.

Comment: Yes, probably, but the column width is defined by "something", because when moving this column (UoM) it keeps that width.